# How do I get Pygame 1.9.2 to work with Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I just installed Pygame 1.9.2 and am running Python 3.3. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it so that when I click the 'X' in my pygame window, the program closes. I believe the following code works with Pygame 1.9.2 and Python 3.2, but is there any way to get it to work on Python 3.3? And what do I have to change to get the right effect? Here is some simple code that illustrates what I mean:

```
# Drawing Lines

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Drawing Lines")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type in (QUIT, KEYDOWN):
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,200))

    #draw the line
    color = 255,255,0
    width = 8
    pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (100,100), (500,400), width)

    pygame.display.update()
```

When I run this, a screen appears with a diagonal line on it, just like it's supposed to, but when I click the 'X' in the top-right corner of the window to close the window, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Exercise Programs\test_code\code\chap02\DrawingLines.py", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit()
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

I guess the line that says sys.exit() is supposed to close the window if this is run in mython 3.2, but it isn't doing this in Python 3.3. The window just freezes and I get that error message. How do I achieve the desired effect in Python 3.3? What line do I need to enter?

Comment: Does it help if you add `import sys` to your script?

Comment: "I believe the following code works with Pygame 1.9.2 and Python 3.2" Have you run the code in 3.2 to verify this belief?

Answer (score 3):

Yo didn't import sys. Just add

```
import sys
```

to your imports, then it should work.

The fact that you see a window with the drawing at all suggests that the program is running fine otherwise.

Comment: I expect to see the screen with the OP's original code. Even if `sys` isn't imported, `sys.exit()` is still syntactically valid. So the program should run successfully up until the user clicks the X button and `sys.exit()` tries to execute.

Comment: ..."When I run this, a screen appears with a diagonal line on it, just like it's supposed to"...? that means it _is_ running and only failing at sys.exit.

Comment: So we agree that you _can_ see the screen when initially running the script. So why did you write "you wouldn't see any screen at all" in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The actual command used to close a project window is `pygame.quit()`.